# Cannot convert CSV to Excel (XLSX)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working in a macro that convert CSV to Excel (xlsx). The problem is that, althought the extension change, the new converted file to excel keeps the structure of a CSV file, I mean, not separated by columns.

```
myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.csv")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)
wb.SaveAs myPath & Replace(myFile, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
wb.Close False
```

Is there something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If you open the CSV in Excel does it split out the data into columns?

Comment: Hi Robin, yes, excel can open my csv properly

Answer (score 0):

Your text file include some characters else of Ansi encoding.
And that need delete "=",  quote. That's delimiter is semi-colon.
Line delimiter is ";;;" three semi-colon(my guess).

```
Sub openCsv()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String, myFile As String
    Dim newFile As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim vR(), vSplit, vSub
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Integer

    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" 'your path
    myFile = "myTest.csv" 'your csv file
    newFile = Split(myFile, ".")(0) & ".xlsx"


    s = TransFromUtf_8(myPath & myFile)
    s = Replace(s, "=", "")
    s = Replace(s, Chr(34), "")

    vSplit = Split(s, ";;;")
    For i = 0 To UBound(vSplit)
        n = n + 1
        vSub = Split(vSplit(i), ";")
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 30, 1 To n)
        For j = 0 To UBound(vSub)
            vR(j + 1, n) = vSub(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
    With Wb
        With .Sheets(1)
            .Cells.NumberFormatLocal = "@"
            .Range("a1").Resize(n, 30) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
            .Columns.AutoFit

        End With
        .SaveAs myPath & newFile
        .Close (0)
    End With

End Sub
Function TransFromUtf_8(myFile As String)
    Dim objStream
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile myFile
        TransFromUtf_8 = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Dy.Lee, but that is not working neither. Below, what the CSV file contains (only one row showed). ";" is not the only separator.. hope this help.



                            
              





    ="SUBSCRIPTION";"=""345901005599418""";"=""2017-05""";"=""345901005599418""";"=""8934075100252227624""";"=""214074302328015""";"INACTIVE_NEW";;;"36659331";"00000";"1";"default1";"Default Subscription Group";"=""UNKNOWN""";"0";"Euro";"No";;;;"";"";"";"";;"

Comment: @AlejandroHdez Can  you describe your text  file and what you want result.

Comment: Yor text is not sepersted by delimeter coma but ";".

Comment: Semiclon format number is  4. And your  case some  more  need. What is delimeter which Seperate row .

Comment: @AlejandroHdez:  modified code.  test  with your text file.

Comment: Thanks @Dy.Lee!. I'll check tomorrow and back to you.m!

Comment: fornutaley, my CSV is easier than you supposed.. sorry for don't inform you in advance. ";;;"three semicolon is only used when that field is empty, not a line delimeter. Your code is awsome,  but I need to tune it, because excel file looks messy, I mean, several carry return where shouldn't have any, etc.  i need time to tune it and understand how array works. Could you please share the code for this case, I mean, when triple semi colon means only that fields are empty? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AlejandroHdez: It is needed  that you show the textfile image, and image of sample result in excel.

Comment: Hi @Dy.Lee, I'm afraid I cannot insert images yet.. can I send you it to your email?

Comment: I'm trying to adapt the code to my file. What is the aim of ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 30, 1 To n) ? I can't understand it. ReDim Preserve keep the contain while resize second bound.. that is the theory, but I don't really understand its use here. Any help?

Comment: I think that the idea is to split the string after X number of semi-colon, as every line contains the same numbers of semi-colon. Any idea? Many thanks!